# Tabbar images not sizing right for iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

The tab bar image is not getting resized when I set for iPad only but works fine if I set it for all devices.

Goal when its an iPhone/iTouch have no tab bar image. When its iPad show tab bar image.

Working code when i set it to all devices:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Emergency Management", @"Emergency Management");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"swoosh"];      
    }
    return self;
}
```

Code not working when set to iPad only:

```
 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Emergency Management", @"Emergency Management");
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"swoosh"];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

What it looks like all messed up:

[image]

As you can see the first 4 are normal using the first code but when you set it for iPad its all messed up.

Comment: This behavior is weird. But I’m curious why you’re only setting a tab-bar image for one device family in the first place. Is your view controller presented in a tab bar on iPhone? If so, are you using a different image? If not, there’s no harm in setting the `tabBarItem.image` anyway.

Comment: On the iPhone the images are to big for the list view and it makes it so you cannot read the wording so I choose to just not show images in the more tab.